# C# Why sometime Thread not wakeup after sleeping

Tags: c#, thread-sleep, wakeup

I have a Thread, with a loop:

```
While (IsRunning){
     Scan DB
     If (having Data) then Enqueue
     Else {
        Log.Debug("No Data");
        Sleep(onePeriod);
     }
}
```

Why sometime, my thread no wake up after sleep a period?

I check log (Log by `Common.Logging.Log4Net`), my thread write log periodically when no data, and suddenly do nothing when other threads still keep running.

Please help me.

My code:

```
while (_isRunning)
{
#region Check if not Online
try
{
    if (!Tw2iConfig.IsOnlineEnable())
    {
        if (Tw2iConfig.CheckShowDebugLoop(ref loopViewTimeIncasOnline))
            Log.Debug(string.Format("{0}Check Server online: Time OFFLINE! Sleep {1}ms truoc khi recheck!"
                , prefixLog, Tw2iConfig.SleepWhenCheckOnlineIncas));
        Thread.Sleep(Tw2iConfig.SleepWhenCheckOnlineIncas);
        continue;
    }
} catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(string.Format("{0}Check config error", prefixLog), ex);
    if (!_isRunning) break;
    Thread.Sleep(Tw2iConfig.SleepScanCMSRequest);
    continue;
}
#endregion

#region Loop get Data from DB
bool requireSleep = false;
try
{
    //Neu ko trong thoi gian Online day => Sleep
    var requestDatas = requestDataDal.GetRequestData((int)RequestStatus.NewRequest);
    if (requestDatas == null || requestDatas.Count == 0)
    {
        Log.Debug(string.Format("{0}Query DB: no RequestData(s) found! Sleep {1}ms before re-scan DB!"
                        , prefixLog, Tw2iConfig.SleepScanCMSRequest));              
        requireSleep = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Info(string.Format("{0}Query DB: found {1} RequestData(s)! Loop & enqueue!"
                    , prefixLog, requestDatas.Count));
        foreach (RequestData requestData in requestDatas)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_isRunning)
                    break;
                // While Queue Full -> no Enqueue more data!!!
                DateTime loopView = DateTime.Now;
                while (MsgQueue.ShareInstance.IsFull())
                {
                    if (!_isRunning)
                        break;
                    if (Tw2iConfig.CheckShowDebugLoop(ref loopView))
                        Log.Debug(string.Format("{0}Query full, hang Request {2}. Wait & sleep {1}ms"
                                    , prefixLog, Tw2iConfig.SleepQueueFull, requestData.RequestId));
                    Thread.Sleep(Tw2iConfig.SleepQueueFull);
                }
                // Add CmsChannel to RequestData to be able to response right!!!
                requestData.CmsChannel = cmsChannel;
                ProcessOne(requestData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(string.Format("{0}Error when wait & enqueue RequestData [Id: {1}]",
                    prefixLog, requestData == null ? -1 : requestData.RequestId), ex);
            }
        }
    }
} catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(string.Format("{0}Loi query RequestData(s)", prefixLog), ex);
    requireSleep = true;
}
#endregion

if (!_isRunning) break;
if (requireSleep)
        Thread.Sleep(Tw2iConfig.SleepScanCMSRequest);   
}
```